# Как поверх absolut'a накладывать информацию? (html/css)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Делаю слайдер, даю четырем картинкам positin:absolute, и сверху пытаюсь ввести какой то текст, но он не выводится, потому что находиться под картинками. **Что сделать что бы картинки были друг под другом и в них можно было размещать объекты?(текст/изображения/блоки)**

[image: Мой код]
Всем четырем картинкам стоит position: absolute; и текст не выводится, он под картинками, почему? как сделать?

[image: css]

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Если возможно, попробуйте обернуть каждое изображение `div`-om, включите в этот же блок текст, присвойте нужный `#slider` и вращайте блоки, а не изображения. Надеюсь, это вам поможет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код в тело вопроса текстом, а не изображением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте!
Вы не правильно используете bootstrap.
Bootstrap уже имеет в себе готовый [слайдер](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

Если вы не хотите использовать его в своём проекте - обратите внимание, как он реализован.

Если отказаться от того, что предлагает bootstrap:
Изображения вам требуется обернуть в дополнительные блоки. Абсолютное позиционирование примеряете к родительскому блоку и к блоку с текстом, который вы хотите отображать поверх изображения.

В дополнение:
у вас для всех экранов прописан одинаковый размер. Вам достаточно указывать только col-sm-12. (в данном случае bootstrap применит указанный вами размер для всех экранов большего размера)

т.е.

```
class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
```

равносилен

```
class="col-sm-12"
```